# Devtools not waiting for less to recompile css

Tags: css, google-chrome, gruntjs, less, google-chrome-devtools

I have a grunt configuration to generate `css` files from `less`.  I have a watcher set, which is also generating the source-map and everything seems to be working fine except...

When I change the `.less` file in devtools, I get a message in console saying:

```
http://localhost/url/to/my.css?ver=3.9 resource missing.  Please
reload the page.
```

Which means my styles don't auto-refresh after I've changed the `.less` inside dev tools.  I have also noted that this message pops up before grunt is finished re-generating the `.css` file.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Okay found it!!  The problem turns out to be with wordpress.

when `using wp_enqueue_style(...)` it automatically appends a version number in the link to the resource (both CSS and JS).

To remove this, you can add this code inside your functions.php file

```
function remove_cssjs_ver( $src ) {
        if( strpos( $src, '?ver=' ) )
            $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
        return $src;
    }
        add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_cssjs_ver', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_cssjs_ver', 10, 2 );
```

Then your devtools should be running like a bomb!!  Who would have thought?  WordPress :(